# Cannot find Facebook dependency in Spring

Tags: maven, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api

I'm using maven in my Spring Boot application. I want to make a Facebook login so I followed the official Spring tutorial(https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/). I think there is an issue with the following dependency:

```
@Controller
public class FacebookController
{
private Facebook facebook;
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

public FacebookController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
    this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
    if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
        return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
    }

    model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
    PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
    model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
    return "hello";
}
}
```

I'm using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

but I've also tried version 1.1.1 RELEASE.

I've researched similar questions but they doesn't work for me([Maven cannot find spring social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593799/maven-cannot-find-spring-social/26596491)).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement, Spring Social has been EOL'd since July 2018.

We are in the middle of taking down the Spring Social-based guides from the list of officially supported guides found at https://spring.io/guides/.